# How to add custom views on lock screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, customization, jailbreak, lockscreen

I am new to develop jailbroaken iphone apps. I'd like to add my own views, such as button, on the lockscreen and do some simple tasks, but i have no idea what api or function to use. Can I do that by using a special template(like writing custom notification widget)? Or add subviews on a specific view?

Comment: Have you [looked at this question yet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11602574/119114)?  It's generally good information to familiarize yourself with, for these kinds of tweaks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That should work. I already dumped the Springboard headers and now I'm working on finding the classes which control the lock screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my logos code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpringBoard/SBAwayController.h>
%hook SBAwayController
- (void)lock
{
    %orig;

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 280, 50);
    [btn setTitle:@"Hello Notification" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(unlock)] autorelease];
    [btn addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [[[objc_getClass("SBAwayController") sharedAwayController] awayView] addSubview:btn];

    return;
}
%end
```

when I lock the screen, the button is added to the lockscreen.