# How to create apple mail plugin for Mac OS X

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, apple-mail

I want to make apple mail plugin but I don't know anything like!

1. From where to start?
2. which application in Xcode I suppose to chose for Apple mail plugin
   (In create new Project)
3. Can we develop this thing in Objective-C? or need other thing to
   know.
4. Is there any Tutorial for this issue?

I also find for this issue on stack but not getting proper help
I Also look on  [How to create Apple mail plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720536/how-to-create-apple-mail-plugin)

on stack overflow but not satisfied with the answer.

Thanks for any Suggestion or Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no official plugin support in the Mail.app.
Apple is pretty restrictive with its applications.

Anyways, there is a project which integrates PGP since years into Mail.app and its still supported by the original developer.

Check [GPGMail](https://github.com/GPGTools/GPGMail). The source is freely available via GitHub and should give you a first overview or and project template for Mail.app plugins.

Comment: Can i add Small window OR View in MailBox list(Left sidebar) in apple mail ?

Comment: What you should do is to find any notification you can attach to get an element where you probally can access parts of the window. This requires a lot of reverse engineering but its possible. Another approach would be to use [NSApp mainWindow] after your plugin instance has been loaded. Save the pointer and inject your view where ever you want. This requires some try and error to find out which subview is the container you want to inject your view. Some people do that approach when injecting menus or something else into Xcode.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan, Have you able to add left sidebar in apple mail app?