# Creating a plugin for Apple Mail

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, apple-mail

I'm looking for some documentation how to create an apple mail plugin for mac os but without too much luck. Is there any good documentation, sample, tutorial... that explain it? I've found sample posts but the newest one is from 5 years ago. Anyone has a clue about it? I wonder if something have changed since then.

Some posts that I found:

- [2014] [How to create Apple mail plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720536/how-to-create-apple-mail-plugin)
- [2007] https://adamnash.blog/2007/09/17/getting-ready-to-write-an-apple-mailapp-plug-in-for-mac-os-x/
- [2015] https://myjeeva.com/mail-app-plugin-development.html

Comment: got any luck? am still looking for one same here.

Comment: Seems that all must be done through private APIs so no support from Apple and high risk of any change by them in a future would break any part of it.

Comment: I'm looking for this too.
I'm open to using private API's, do we know if commercial App extensions will get approved and allowed in App store if they used private APIs ?

Comment: If your app is distributed using AppStore, it will need to get reviewed by Apple, if they detect that you are using a private call, it can be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here is the documentation for mailkit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mailkit/build_mail_app_extensions

Also with a video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10168/

Answer (score 0):

There wasn’t a great solution at the time you posted but in Monterey there is a MailKit extension that finally provides public APIs. It doesn’t seem to have everything yet, but it’s at least the beginning